# Send email when order status is changed

Tags: rules, emails, commerce

I need to send a message to the customer when I change the order status (e.g from pending to processing-completed-canceled). How can I do this with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/Rules)?

Answer (score 3):

Rules is definitely the way to do this.

1. Create a new rule...

Name: Order Status Update
Tags:
React on event: **Commerce order > After updating an existing commerce order**

2. Then, add an action. **System > Send mail**
3. Email "To" value. Use the **[commerce-order:mail]** token
4. Fill out subject and message. Then save.

Updated: To make sure you dont send an email everytime the order is updated, set the following rules...

1. Add condition: Data Comparison. Commerce-order:status = Completed
2. Add "AND".
3. Add condition: Data Comparison. **Commerce-order-unchanged:status = Completed**, but check NEGATE.

This avoids having to enable the [PHP filter](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/php) module.

Comment: Note: This will send an email whenever the order is updated at all, so you may need to add a condition to the rule for the order status.

Comment: I have done that using the following
1. Event
After updating an existing commerce order
2. Condition 
Data to compare: [commerce-order:status], Data value: Processing
3.Action
Parameter: To: [commerce-order:mail], Subject: The status of your order..., Message: The status of your order..., From: [site:mail]

The problem is that the mail is sent only when the status is "processing". I need the same for "completed" and "canceled"

Comment: I see, so perhaps an additional condition to compare the order status field with text? E.g compare order status with "completed" and send if it matches? I'm away for the weekend else I'd tell you exactly how I did it, but can't remember off the top of my head

Comment: Hi @Collins, i am wondering if you have found the way to do that

Comment: Fabrica: you could clone the rule and edit it so that you have one for "processing", one for "completed" and a final one for "canceled".

Answer (score 0):

Set up the rule to use "Event After updating an existing commerce order". Add the condition "Execute custom PHP code". Then add the following code.

```
if("[commerce-order:status]" == "completed" && "[commerce-order-unchanged:status]" != "[commerce-order:status]") { return TRUE; } else { return FALSE; }
```

Then you can set up your email action.

Answer (score 0):

It took me entirely too long to figure out how to do this with rules only, but here's what I have working:

```
OR
    AND
        Data comparison
        Parameter: Data to compare: [commerce-order:status], Data value (equals): Canceled

        NOT Data comparison
        Parameter: Data to compare: [commerce-order-unchanged:status], Data value (equals): Canceled

    AND
        Data comparison
        Parameter: Data to compare: [commerce-order:status], Data value (equals): Processing

        NOT Data comparison
        Parameter: Data to compare: [commerce-order-unchanged:status], Data value (equals): Processing
```

If you need additional status updates, you'll have to create and wrap each one so rules knows what to check through.  I left out "Completed" because I want a completely custom message sent on completed orders.

Shoutout to @Colton Echols for making me mentally think it through with the php snippet.